# Writing data to datastore using jupyter notebook on Azure Ml studio

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, azure-machine-learning-service

Hi I have prepared some data from saved table from Datastore on Jupyter notebook from Azre ML studio. Now, I want to write the prepared data back to a datastore using the same notebook.

Please help me with some examples.

Note: Here i have connected my ADLS Gen2 to datastore.

Answer (score 0):

Integration work include enabling all datastore types to be consumable by data prep/dataset. This is very important as data prep/dataset is the engine that powers the data ingestion story for AzureML and being able to support all datastore types is crucial in making this a reality. Runs that involves reading and writing to datastore using data prep/dataset.
The table below presents what we currently support.
[image]